# Is it possible to turn vibration on/off on Sony Smartwatch 2 (by application)?

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I want to enable/disable vibration on Sony Smartwatch 2 in my app on some conditions.

Is it possible and if it so how to do that?

EDIT: I mean enable/disable it **globally** (notifications, incoming calls etc.), as "Vibrate" setting in SW2 menu.

Comment: @ericbn I tried nothing because I entirely don't know how to do that.

Comment: Did you try Google? You'd have found http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html ...

Comment: @ElDuderino `Vibrator` is absolutely not that I need. I need to turn vibration on/off globally, like `AudioManager.setVibrateSetting` but on SW2. This question is about Sony API, rather than Android API.

Comment: Do you mean you want to enable/disable vibration for notifications on some conditions?

Comment: @Pete For notifications and other things like incoming call, not vibration called from my application.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be able to do this globally.

From the [docs](https://developer.sony.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/extension/util/control/ControlExtension), the watch operates on actions from the host.

I don't have a SW2 right now but you can try to trigger the extension when you detect the device is vibrating.

This would be a start:

```
public class NoVibrator extends ControlExtension{


// stuff....

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        if(hasVibrator()){
            stopVibrator();
     }
    }

}
```

But I suspect this only disables vibration in your app.

You might have to find an exploit to change the settings. (something like [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7890))

Comment: Suddenly `stopVibrator()` just makes vibrator active for some amount of time. It seems that this method can only interrupt vibration with infinite repeats (and only between iterations of on/off cycle). Anyway, thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your conditions are but to control the vibration use these methods in the [ControlExtension](https://developer.sony.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/extension/util/control/ControlExtension/) class:

Start:

```
ControlExtension.startVibrator(int onDuration, int offDuration, int repeats);
```

Stop:

```
ControlExtension.stopVibrator();
```

Edit 1:
There is no way to configure vibration for notifications.